# Sayコマンドのやり方。

Tags: python, python3, discord

Discordのbotをpythonで製作しているのですが、Sayコマンド(botにしゃべらせる)の書き方を教えてください。
この方法を試しても無理でした。

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot # インストールした discord.py

client = discord.Client() # 接続に使用するオブジェクト

# 起動時に通知してくれる処理
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

async def Msay(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
    return await client.say(mesg)
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(''):
        channel = client.get_channel('')
        reply = ''
        await client.send_message(channel, reply)
    if message.content.startswith('!/shutdown'):
        channel = client.get_channel('')
        reply = ''
        await client.send_message(channel, reply)
    if message.content.startswith(''):
        channel = client.get_channel('')
        reply = ''
        await client.send_message(channel, reply)
    if message.content.startswith(''):
        role = discord.utils.get(message.author.server.roles, name="")
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, f'{message.author.mention} ')

# botの接続と起動
# （tokenにはbotアカウントのアクセストークンを入れてください）
client.run('token')
```

Comment: 「無理でした」というのは、何かエラーが出たのでしょうか？　それとも、エラーは出なかったものの思ったような挙動にならなかったのでしょうか？

Comment: [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) をお使いでしょうか？　もしそうであれば、discord.py のバージョンを教えて頂きたいです。`pip show discord.py` で表示されるかと思います。